# Transpiling Typescript into Javascript results in a module import error because of a missing .js suffix

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm just getting into typescript and my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

and when I import a module in my typescript file I import it as

```
import {something} from "./coolfilename"
```

However, whenever I run tsc, the modules go to

```
import {something} from "./coolfilename"
```

but node wants it to be

```
import {something} from "./coolfilename.js"
```

but writing

```
import {something} from "./coolfilename.ts"
```

also throws an error

What does it want us to do???

Comment: I believe if you write the import with the `.js` suffix it will work (even if your filenames are _actually `.ts`.)

Comment: @Evert nah, I get yelled at that they can't find the module

Comment: If your wanting to use Typescript with node,  have you looked at ts-node?,  https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node. No need to use tsc then, also saves having transpired files cluttering the directory.

Comment: I'm currently using ts-node but I'm ready to ship the code. Shouldn't I be shipping the code as js?

Comment: I use TS-node in production, but yes if your shipping for 3rd party or npm you will want to transpile.  Not sure why node is wanting the `.js` extension, are you running node in esm mode?, I still use commonjs, Typescript transpiles Esm modules anyway.

Comment: to be honest I never checked that, how do I check if node is in esm mode?